# easiest way to remove invalid characters from a xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, character

I have a xml file with invalid characters. I searched through internet and haven't found any other way than reading the file as a text file and replace invalid characters one by one.

Can somebody please tell me an easiest way to remove invalid characters from a xml file..

ex xml stream:

```
<Year>where 12 > 13 occures </Year>
```

Comment: What's producing the invalid XML? Can you fix that instead?

Comment: no that is not an option

Comment: is your stream/file a valid xml??? I mean, do you want to filter the value inside the nodes or you want to correct your corrupted xml-file itself???

Comment: There is no easy way, because you need to use some heuristics to detect whether the angle bracket should be replaced because it really is text or that it should be left alone because it belongs to a tag. A more complex example demonstrates this: `<Root><Tag>Where X<Y>Z</Tag>`. Maybe you could utilize an HTML library, because they already do something like this when they read HTML.

Comment: @Patrick I cant load the xml file so itz a corrupted file

Comment: If it was binary data instead of XML, and if it was bad data, you would be asking the sender to fix it.

Comment: More information on you development and deployment environment / language would help formulate a precise answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would try [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). At least better than trying to parse manually.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
hdoc.LoadHtml("<Year>where 12 > 13 occures </Year>");

using(StringWriter wr = new StringWriter())
{
   using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(wr,
           new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
   {
       hdoc.Save(xmlWriter);
       Console.WriteLine(wr.ToString());
   }
}
```

this outputs:

```
<year>where 12 &gt; 13 occures </year>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by thinking of the question differently. Your problem is that the input isn't valid XML. So you actually want to remove invalid characters from a non-XML file. That might sound pedantic, but it immediately indicates that tools designed for processing XML will be no use to you, because your input is not XML.

Fixing the problem at source is always better than trying to repair the damage later. But it you are going to embark on a repair strategy, the first thing is to define precisely what faults in the data you want to repair and how you intend to repair them. It's also a good idea to say clearly what constraints you apply to the solution: for example, does it matter if your repair accidentally changes the contents of any comments or CDATA sections?

Once you have defined your repair strategy: e.g. "replace any & by `&amp;` if it is not immediately followed by either #nn; or #xnn; or a name followed by ';', coding it up becomes quite straightforward.